# How to use select all in angular material select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

can any one use the below array data in the below url

```
[{"columnName":"Column 1 - Type of Medication\n  Number of Medications","selected":false},{"columnName":"Column 2 - Placebo\n(N=7)\nn (%)","selected":false},{"columnName":"Column 3 - Perampanel\n(N=25)\nn (%)","selected":true},{"columnName":"Column 4 - Combined Total\n(N=32)\nn (%)","selected":true}]
```

[Stackblitz URL](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-jsgvx6?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html)

i am not able to use the above array data instead of existing data to select all and de select all

Comment: Did you update the component html respective to the above array?

Comment: yes but in html i am unable to set value to select all

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77887104/3339907

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the array, it depends on what field you are trying to use for `mat-select`. If you take a closer look, your array in the question, has `selected` field, which don't have unique values, like the array you used in SB ('key'). `mat-select` data-binding doesn't work based on `true/false` flag, rather it compares the values given to it and the values in the actual array. So, for your array, you will have to use `columnName` field, since each of them are unique.

You can also add your own custom field in the array, something like `id`, and use it to control mat-select.

I have coded stackblitz to use `columnName`, but added code for using `id` also (commented out). You can uncomment those lines to try it out.

[SB link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-kruupz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.component.html)

app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.searchUserForm = this.fb.group({
      userType: new FormControl(''),
    });

    // if you dont prefer using columnName, insert fake ids, which I suggest you do
    // let i = 1;
    // this.userTypeFilters.forEach((item) => {
    //   item['id'] = i;
    //   i++;
    // });
  }

  tosslePerOne(all) {
    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      this.allSelected.deselect();
      return false;
    }
    if (
      this.searchUserForm.controls.userType.value.length ==
      this.userTypeFilters.length
    )
      this.allSelected.select();
  }
  toggleAllSelection() {
    if (this.allSelected.selected) {
      // if using columnName
      this.searchUserForm.controls.userType.patchValue([
        ...this.userTypeFilters.map((item) => item.columnName),
        0,
      ]);

      // if using id
      // this.searchUserForm.controls.userType.patchValue([
      //   ...this.userTypeFilters.map((item) => item['id']),
      //   0,
      // ]);
    } else {
      this.searchUserForm.controls.userType.patchValue([]);
    }
  }
```

app.component.html:

```
    <!-- if using id, then replace with this [value]="filters.id"-->
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let filters of userTypeFilters"
      [value]="filters.columnName"
      (click)="tosslePerOne(allSelected.viewValue)"
    >
```