# Angular material multiselect dropdown with select all option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, multi-select

I am using angular material multiselect with select all option.
 Refer the stackblitz link below.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-znfehg?file=app/app.component.html 
Currently whichever options I select appear in the textbox of multiselect which is desired behaviour. 
I want to display only "All" text when I select all options, instead of showing each and every item In the list.
I tried several ways with template reference variable but it is not working. Kindly help on this.

Comment: This is the exact same question with the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580095/select-all-mat-option-and-deselect-all

Comment: Not quite the same question - this user wants to know how to display "All" instead of the list of selected items.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `onSelectionChange` event on `mat-option` element to check if all options are checked, and then nest your 'all' checkbox into an `ngIf`

in app.component.html:

```html
<mat-select placeholder="User Type" formControlName="userType" multiple>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let filters of userTypeFilters" (onSelectionChange)="change($event)" [value]="filters.key">
    {{filters.value}}
  </mat-option>
  <div *ngIf="allChecked">
    <mat-option #allSelected (click)="toggleAllSelection()" [value]="0">All</mat-option>
  </div>
</mat-select>
```

add the following in app.component.ts:

```js
change(event) {
  if(event.isUserInput) {
    console.log(event.source.value, event.source.selected);
    // Todo: check if all field are checked
    this.allChecked = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mat-select-trigger` is specifically provided for customizing the display of selections. In your case, there is some work that you need to do to filter out '0' from the actual selections, and to unselect 'All' when an item is unselected, but generally you can do something like the following to change the display to `All` when you select the 'All' checkbox:

```
<mat-select ...>
  <mat-select-trigger>
    {{searchUserForm.controls.userType.value.length >= 4 ? 'All' : searchUserForm.controls.userType.value}}
  </mat-select-trigger>
  ...
</mat-select>
```

The actual condition check will depend on how you implement selection of all items in your model.