# Extend MatOption to create select/deselect all component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ivy

I need to create a *shared component* to *select/deselect all* elements of a `mat-select` because I have an app that use it a lot of times and  implement the same piece of work frequently is not an option.

I've been reading many options, like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580095/select-all-mat-option-and-deselect-all), and I decide to create a component as one of the answers propose (look at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-all-option)

The problem is that with angular v10 it doesn't seems to work. If I click on the Select All button it doens't work, but  If I click on some op the options and then I click on Select All it works, but it doesn't work as expected. The code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-option

The main difference between projects is `Ivy compiler`. Without Ivy, it works.

Is it possible to achieve this with `Ivy compiler`? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has something to do with how Ivy handles listeners inheritance. `_selectViaInteraction` is already called within `MatOption` component because it also contains `click` host listener.

Try remove `this._selectViaInteraction();` in select-all-option.component.ts at 23 line.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-all-option-dmcb4h?file=src/app/select-all-option/select-all-option.component.ts