# angular mat-select select all for more than one select

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to do select all for angular multiple selects, it works for one select but how can I make it work when you have more than 1 select? when i add select all for second input it selects all on first input

**campaign.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('mySel') skillSel: MatSelect;

  toggleAllSelection() {
    this.allSelected = !this.allSelected;

    if (this.allSelected) {
      this.skillSel.options.forEach( (item : MatOption) => item.select());
    } else {
      this.skillSel.options.forEach( (item : MatOption) => {item.deselect()});
    }
  }
```

**campaign.html**

```
  <mat-select #mySel multiple formControlName="Branch">
        <mat-option [value]="0" (click)="toggleAllSelection()">All items</mat-option>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let item of centers" [value]="item.centerCode">{{item.address}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>

        <mat-select #mySel multiple formControlName="categoryDescriptions">
          <mat-option [value]="0" (click)="toggleAllSelection()">All items</mat-option>
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of categories" [value]="item.description">{{item.description}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
```

Comment: For mat-select Select all and Deselect all try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580470/8213994) solution.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer i tried this too, but I have the same problem, how can i make this work when you have more than one select?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66163651/7821499 i have opened a question for that answer too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a single variable `allSelected` to control both of the `mat-select` boxes, and you have also given both `mat-select` boxes the same ID of `mySel`. This is why it selects all on the first `mat-select` when you use the select all option in the second one.

To fix this, give each `mat-select` a different ID e.g `mySelBranch` and `mySelCategory`:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Branch</mat-label>
  <mat-select #mySelBranch [formControl]="branch" multiple>
    <mat-option [value]="0" (click)="toggleAllSelection(mySel)">All items</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let branch of branchList" [value]="branch">{{branch}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Category</mat-label>
  <mat-select #mySelCategory [formControl]="categoryDescriptions" multiple>
    <mat-option [value]="0" (click)="toggleAllSelection(mySel2)">All items</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categoryList" [value]="category">{{category}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And you'll notice I've also changed the call to `toggleAllSelection` - it now passes the mat-select in as a parameter.

The `toggleAllSelection` has been changed to:

```
toggleAllSelection(matSelect: MatSelect) {
    const isSelected: boolean = matSelect.options
      // The "Select All" item has the value 0, so find that one
      .filter((item: MatOption) => item.value === 0)
      // Get the value of the property 'selected' (this tells us whether "Select All" is selected or not)
      .map((item: MatOption) => item.selected)
      // Get the first element (there should only be 1 option with the value 0 in the select)
      [0];

    if (isSelected) {
      matSelect.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => item.select());
    } else {
      matSelect.options.forEach((item: MatOption) => item.deselect());
    } 
}
```

The first part of the function looks through the options of the `mat-select` passed in as a paramter, and finds the option with the value `0` (due to how you've defined your HTML, the "Select All" option always has the value `0`). It then gets the value of the property name `selected` (this will be `true` is "Select All" is selected and false if it is deselected). As the result of this is an array, it then uses `[0]` to get the first item (there should only be a single item in the array at this point because of the `filter` function used:

```
const isSelected: boolean = matSelect.options
  .filter((item: MatOption) => item.value === 0)
  .map((item: MatOption) => item.selected)[0];
```

You no longer need the following variables in your TypeScript class:

```
@ViewChild("mySel") skillSel: MatSelect;
allSelected = false;
```

Please see [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9tkqx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts) for a demo.

Comment: thank u so much for your answer! one more question when i submit my form value of select all (0) is submitted in json array, how can i remove it and submit form with other options value?

Comment: Not sure how your form is set up, but in my StackBlitz the form field value contains 0 as well as the other values when "Select All" is ticked. If that's the same for you, you can remove the 0 by doing `this.branch.value.filter(v => v !== 0)` Have a look at the `submit()` function in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r9tkqx-7ativn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts) which is called when you click the Submit button