# How to add all select checkbox in mat-select -Angular

Tags: angular, material-ui

I have mat-select dropdown to select all or some items.I am struggling to select all or none items.
in HTML file:

```
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-100">
     <mat-label>{{labels.criteria.name}}</mat-label>
     <mat-select formControlName="criteria" multiple  [(ngModel)]="selected">
       <mat-option *ngFor="let criterion of options.criteria" 
         [value]="criterion.value">
         {{criterion.text}}
       </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
   </mat-form-field>
```

in TS file:

```
  selected = [];
     constructor(
       private service: InterviewService, 
       @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Interview
       ) {}
   ngOnInit() {
    this.selected = this.data.criteria.map(criterion => {
    return criterion.id;
     });
    }
  onSubmit(): void {
   const data = this.formGroup.value;
   data.criteria = data.criteria.map((item: number) => {
     return { id: item };
     });
  }
```

I am putting the selected items on this array(this.selected).
& sending the array of selected id's onSubmit().

How can I select all items in this array?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select All mat option and deselect All](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580095/select-all-mat-option-and-deselect-all)

Comment: As i used [(ngModel)]="selected", this solution didn't work actually.

Comment: [Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form directives has been deprecated in Angular v6 and is scheduled for removal in a future version of Angular.](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel-is-deprecated)

Comment: Can you put your code in a stackblitz ?