# Angular 10 "select all"-option in a mat-select multiselect

Tags: angular, typescript, drop-down-menu, angular-material, form-control

I am using a mat-select multiple and I am trying to implement a "select all" option inside of the dropdown.

[Select All Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOVJI.png)

My mat-select is connected to a FormControl.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="'exampleControl'" multiple>
    <mat-option (click)="toggleAllSelection()">All</mat-option>
    <mat-option (click)="toggleSingleSelection()" *ngFor="let currentValue of allValues"
                [value]="currentValue">{{currentValue}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

The Problem I am facing is the following: In the shown Dropdown all Options are selected, which are part of the FormControl.value. But the "All"-Value is NEVER part of the FormControl, so its basically never selected. But well, I want it to be selected, whenever all Options are selected. But I dont want it to be Part of the FormControl. I hope I described the Problem understandably.

Comment: You will need to bind a value to the `All` option too. Take a look at this, it's pretty much what you want I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580095/select-all-mat-option-and-deselect-all