# Make Angular Material UI accessible and add on load check values

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui, accessibility

I have an angular material drop down selector where I have multiple options to choose from. There is also an option where I can select all the options at once. 
[image]

 
I used the code from this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-jsgvx6?file=app/app.component.html), ( found it in answer for a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51580095/select-all-mat-option-and-deselect-all) ).

These are my problems

1. **The solution that was given in stack blitz is not fully accessible. The events do not get triggered on click of space bar.** 
   What I have tried : using (onSelectionChange) event. But this will throw *" Maximum call stack size exceeded"* error as soon as there is a change.
2. **How do I check these ( select all ) options on load ?** 
   What I have tried : adding [checked]=true. But this will throw *"Can't
   bind to 'checked' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'"* error.

How do I achieve these behaviours ?

Comment: Can you show the code you've put together? The issue with your item 1 is that you have code in your onSelectionChange that triggers another selectionchange and the recursion eventually fills up the call stack and ... well you know the rest :)

Comment: Hi, @Peter4499, my current code snippet is pretty much similar to the one stackblitz link I have added in the question. [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-jsgvx6?file=app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a hack ( or an actual solution ) for this problem. Feel free to edit my code**
Turns out I wasn't the only one with the same problem.
Even though there were lot of people with the same issue under this [link](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9149). My problem was slightly different. I wanted even the 'All' option to be accessible via keyboard. And I had to load all the options on load.

Here's the code that I wrote for it :

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="ddHolder">
  <div>
    <form [formGroup]="selectYearsForm" autocomplete="off" >
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-select formControlName="yearOption" multiple class="custom-select-csRp"
          panelClass="custom-select-panelCsrp mat-select-custom scrollcsrp" disableOptionCentering #selectcsrp
          contentTabIndex=null  #matSelect (selectionChange)="matOPtionChanged($event)">
  
          <mat-option #allSelected [value]="0">
            All
          </mat-option>
  
          <mat-option *ngFor="let year of selectedYearDD" [value]="year">
            {{year}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatOption } from '@angular/material/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  toppings = new FormControl();
  selectYearsForm!: FormGroup;
  selectedYears: any = [];
  selectedYearDD: any = [];
  selectedYearDDCopy: any = [];

  
  @ViewChild('allSelected')
  private allSelected!: MatOption;


  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ){

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.selectYearsForm = this.fb.group({
      yearOption: new FormControl('')
    });

    this.selectedYearDD = ['1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005'];
    this.selectedYearDDCopy.push([...this.selectedYearDD.map((item: any) => item), 0])
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    //if needed load all the values by default
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption
        .patchValue([...this.selectedYearDD.map((item: any)=> item), 0]);

      this.selectedYears = [];
      this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption.value.forEach((item: any) => item == 0 ? "" : this.selectedYears.push(item));
  
    }, 1);

  }

  matOPtionChanged(event: { value: number[]; }) {

    const filteredArray = event.value.filter(val => !this.selectedYearDDCopy.includes(val));

    if (event.value.length == this.selectedYearDD.length && !event.value.includes(0)) {
      if (this.allSelected.selected || event.value.length - 1 == this.selectedYearDDCopy.length) {
        this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption
          .patchValue([...this.selectedYearDD.map((item: any)  => item), 0]);
      }
      else {
        this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption
          .patchValue([]);
      }
    }

    else if (filteredArray.length == 1 && filteredArray[0] === 0) {
      this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption
        .patchValue([...this.selectedYearDD.map((item: any)  => item), 0]);
    }

    else if (event.value.includes(0) && event.value.length - 1 < this.selectedYearDD.length) {
      event.value.shift();
      this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption
        .patchValue(event.value);
    }

    this.selectedYearDDCopy = this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption.value;

    this.selectedYears = [];
    this.selectYearsForm.controls.yearOption.value.forEach((item: any)  => item == 0 ? "" : this.selectedYears.push(item));

  }
}
```