# Identify the option that was clicked in a mat-select with multi-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

For a multi-select as shown below, I would like to know which option was last selected by the user in the `selectionChange` event.

The intention is to identify any click to the **'All'** option and ignore it while still being able to process other options in `selectionChange` event.
Any other strategy is also welcome.

[image: screenshot of mat-select with multiple options]

```html
<mat-select
  [multiple]="true"
  formControlName="selectCtrl"
  (selectionChange)="onSelectionChange($event)"
>
    <mat-option
      #allOption
      [value]="allSelectOption"
      (click)="toggleMultiAll(allOption.selected)"
    >
        {{ allSelectOption.displayText }}
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions" [value]="option">
        {{ option.displayText }}
    </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

```js
onSelectionChange(event) {
    if (_condition_) {  // If clicked option is 'All', ignore
        return;
    }
    this.selectedOptions$.next(event.value);
}
```

Comment: See if any of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51580095/5058682) help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `selectionChange()`, you can subscribe to the `optionSelectionChanges`. Every time the selection is changed, it will be triggered.

Please don't forget to unsubscribe when you subscribe to thing. I won't include it here.

### In example.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MatSelect } from '@angular/material/select';

@Component({
  //...
})
export class Example implements AfterViewInit {

  // get the view reference from the html called '#mySelect'
  @ViewChild('mySelect')
  mySelect: MatSelect;

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    // the view reference is only available after the view is initialized. 
    // That's why we have to subscribe in this hook.

    this.mySelect.optionSelectionChanges.subscribe(change => {
      const currentSelect = change.source.value;

      if(currentSelect === 'All') {
         // ... 
      }

    });
  }

}
```

### In example.component.html

```html
<mat-select multiple #mySelect">
  <!-- option here -->    
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the requirement is to identify the last selected/clicked option, and not whether `All` is in the selected list or not.

Comment: @DeepeshKumar I updated the answer to meet your requirement.